# Powershell REGEX extract last word

Tags: regex, powershell

If i have a PowerShell string for example "John Doe Bloggs" or "John Bloggs".
And I wanted to extract the last word after the space so in the above example it would be "Bloggs" what REGEX would I use. The solution must be a REGEX. I've googled my mind away and still not any closer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did you 'google'?  try something like 'regex match end of string'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
$string = 'John Doe Bloggs'
$regex = '.+\s(.+)'
$string -replace $regex,'$1'

Bloggs
```

Answer (score 5):

It's really too bad that the answer "must" be a regex (I'm guessing this is some kind of homework assignment?) because it's pretty simple without.

```
$string = 'John Doe Bloggs';
$string.split(' ')[-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will find the last word in the input:

```
(?<word>\w+)[\s\,\.\?\!]*$
```

The match is in the group named `word` - the entire expression matches the final word and optional whitespace / (some) punctuation. Any trailing whitespace / punctuation will not be part of the `word` group.